# Can I sell only Desktop applications in Windows Store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, marketplace

I am writing this, because I called Microsoft and they can't give me a person to answer these questions and on https://stackoverflow.com/ I found only very old questions about this topic.

1.I have *only* desktop applications. Can I sell them in the  Windows Store?

2.Do I need to buy a Microsoft Action pack subscription to be able to sell in Windows Store, or I simply need to fill the company data?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Add to the second question:
1. You can register the account refer to the step in document: [Opening a developer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account)

2.If you want to sell paid app, you need to [Set up your payout account and tax forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/setting-up-your-payout-account-and-tax-forms)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, you can sell applications in the Microsoft Store, which are only intended to run on desktops and not, for example, on XBox or Windows 10 Mobile. When you submit your app, you can choose for which device familys your app should be available. Please note that if you have a Win32-app, you have to convert it to a `.msix`-installer first, for example using the [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/tool-overview).
2. No, you don't need the action pack subscription, but you need to register a [Microsoft Developer Account](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/store/register/). The one-time fee for such an account is around $19 USD for an individual accound and $99 USD for a company account (the exact value depends on your country), no renewal is required. Students can get a developer account for free.

Comment: Thank you very much!